# Angled mesh pattern using css gradients

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

[image: gradient]

Hello. I'd like to achieve the above result but the best I could come up with is this:

```
body {
  background-color: #0200ff;
  background-size: 65px 65px, 65px 65px;
  background-image:
  repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 46px),
  repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 46px);
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: Yea it looks looks like you accomplished what your asking for it is it spacing that is the problem or angle?

Comment: Sorry .. meant the angle.

Answer (score 0):

```
.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: -200px;
  left: -200px;
  right: -200px;
  bottom: -200px;
  background-color: #0200ff;
  z-index: 100;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(39,38,255,1) 1px, transparent 1px),
  linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(39,38,255,1) 1px, transparent 1px);
  background-size: 60px 60px, 60px 100px, 20px 20px, 20px 20px;
  background-position:-2px -2px, -2px -2px, -1px -1px, -1px -1px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
}
```